# Unix cat command and FIFOs

Tags: unix, console

I'm having a problem understanding this commands:
After doing at the Terminal `mkfifo pipe1` and `mkfifo pipe2`
and executing:

1. `$ echo -n x | cat - pipe1 > pipe2 &`

   I get as a result:

   ```
   [1] 3526
   ```

   Number that tend to increase by the time pass.

   When I run:
2. `$ cat <pipe2 > pipe1`

   the output is:

   ```
   $ echo -n x | cat - pipe1 > pipe2 &
   ```

Can somebody explain whats happening?

1. As far as I know, the first command should create a new file with x + pipe1 content on pipe2 then what's that Output, and if pipe2 already exist because was created with mkfifo then what should happen?
2. I have no idea what the second command does. I can't find any reference online.

This is a homework and we haven't seen the class yet; any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Each command:

```
echo -n x | cat - pipe1 > pipe2 &
```

runs the command sequence such that the output of `echo` is piped to `cat` but the sequence is run in the background.  The shell generates a message such as:

```
[1] 3526
```

to indicate that the background job is jobid 1 and process ID 3526.  Because of the nature of FIFOs, the sub-shell as a whole is hung up waiting for something to open `pipe2` for reading before it can successfully launch the `cat` operation.  Once released,
the `cat` command reads one character from standard input and then hangs waiting for some input from `pipe1`.  Strictly, that means, it waits for a process to open `pipe2` for writing.

As you repeat the command, the numbers increase because job numbers and process IDs are unique.

The `cat pipe1` on its own should hang.  The echoed commands might be from some previous command completing.

```
$ echo -n x | cat - pipe1 > pipe2 &
[1] 9304
$ (echo Hi > pipe1) &
[2] 9305
$ sleep 3
$ jobs
[1]-  Running                 echo -n x | cat - pipe1 > pipe2 &
[2]+  Running                 ( echo Hi > pipe1 ) &
$ cat pipe2
-n x
Hi
[1]-  Done                    echo -n x | cat - pipe1 > pipe2
[2]+  Done                    ( echo Hi > pipe1 )
$
```

My shell (Korn) doesn't interpret `echo -n` the same as yours (probably `bash`).

Comment: Sigh.  **+1**.  There isn't much point to answering questions once Jonathan Leffler has posted an answer.

Comment: We're here to help spread knowledge, not compete.